# Enable "Show Message Content in Popups" by default?

Tags: gnome

For now it is disabled by default and I wonder if there's a way to trigger it to be enabled by default, since I only have a few apps mattering privacy and it would be a bit troublesome to enable it for every newly installed app.

Comment: It's a shame you haven't found anything